# Summary statistics for each group and transpose using pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, scipy, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11,11,11,11,11,11,12,12,12],
                   'time' :[0,0,0,1,2,3,4,4,0,0,1],
                   'value':[101,102,np.nan,120,143,153,160,170,96,97,99]})
```

What I would like to do is

a) Get the summary statistics for each subject for each time point (ex: 0hr, 1hr, 2hr etc)

b) Please note that `NA` rows shouldn't be counted as separate record/row during computing mean

I was trying the below

```
for i in df['subject_id'].unique()
        df[df['subject_id'].isin([i])].time.unique
        val_mean = df.groupby(['subject_id','time']][value].mean()
        val_stddev = df[value].std()
```

But I couldn't get the expected output

I expect my output to be like as shown below where I expect one row for each time point (ex: 0hr, 1 hr , 2hr, 3hr etc). Please note that `NA` rows shouldn't be counted as seperated record/row during computing mean

[image]

Comment: I guess you can try `df.groupby(['person_id', 'time'])['value'].agg(['mean', 'median', 'std'])`

Comment: you can write as an answer and I can accept it

Comment: Let it be. It's just one simple line of code :-)

Comment: @ShubhamSharma but this way it still pops up whenever I search for upvoted & unanswered questions :-)